# How do i add and Force the Screen Resolution on an HDMI output?

Tags: 11.04, video, hdmi

I been trying to add a new resolution for my TV using `xrandr`, but this new resolution doesn't show in Monitors, also when i try to force it my screen just goes black.

Windows correctly detects all the supported modes, while Ubuntu doesn't, Why?, also How do i add a new screen resolution so i can use it without my screen just turning black?.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue and I've yet to try the following solution, but I believe it has to do with the TV/Monitor not sending out the correct EDID.

This wiki page lists some information on the issue and steps for adding a section to your xorg config:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HDMI

You'll want to check the EDID and then try testing modelines. When you get one that works good, you should be able to add it to your xorg config so when you connect in the future it'll work correctly.